# How to emit from a nested component while maintaining ability to reference variables outside of function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage, eventemitter

I am trying to build an image uploading app which uploads images to firebase storage, tracking upload percentage along the way, and updates a gallery on upload so as to show all images including the newly uploaded one.

I began building the component for uploading and tracking the upload progress. However, it did not work as the onUpload() method was unable to change the value of this.uploadPercentage.

```
<template>
  <v-container style="height: 100%;">
      <v-row
        align-content="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <h1>Image Uploader</h1>
      </v-row>
      <v-row
        align-content="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-progress-linear
            color="deep-purple accent-4"
            rounded
            height="6"
            :value="uploadPercentage"
            id="uploader"
          ></v-progress-linear>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row
        align-content="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <v-col
          class="align-content-center"
          cols="4"
        >
          <v-file-input
            v-model="file"
            accept="image/*"
            label="choose an image"
            outlined
            @change="onFileChange"
            ></v-file-input>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          class="align-content-center mt-2"
          cols="2"
        >
          <v-btn
            @click="onUpload"
          >
            Upload
            <v-icon right dark>mdi-cloud-upload</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from '@/firebase/init'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    file: null,
    imageURL: null,
    uploadPercentage: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    onFileChange () {
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = () => {
        reader.imagUrl = reader.result
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.file)
    },
    onUpload () {
      // create a firebase storage ref
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('public_wall/' + this.file.name)

      // upload file
      var task = storageRef.put(this.file)

      // update progress bar
      task.on('state_changed',
        function (snapshot) {
          console.log('uploading')
          var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          this.uploadPercentage = percentage
        },

        function error (err) {
          console.log(err)
        },

        function completed () {
          console.log('upload complete')
        }

      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I figured out that this was because of the scope of functions, and that changing the snapshot funciton in task.on() to an arrow function I was able to get around this problem.

```
task.on('state_changed',
        snapshot => {
          console.log('uploading')
          var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          this.uploadPercentage = percentage
        },
```

However, I want this component to be a nested component and to emit a signal when the upload is complete. In order to do this, I have tried changing the completed function in task.on() to the following:

```
function completed () {
          console.log('upload complete function')
          this.$emit('upload-complete', 'hello')
        }
```

This throws the error: TypeError: this.$emit is not a function.

Through some research I have found that you cannot reference this.$emit from within an arrow function, however, the completed function is not an arrow function, and changing the snapshot function back to non-arrow doesn't solve the problem, only stops the upload percentage tracker from working.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because **This** refers to something else inside the completed function. You can do something like this

```
onUpload () {
  let _self = this // saving reference to this
  // create a firebase storage ref
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('public_wall/' + this.file.name)

  // upload file
  var task = storageRef.put(this.file)

  // update progress bar
  task.on('state_changed',
    function (snapshot) {
      console.log('uploading')
      var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      this.uploadPercentage = percentage
    },

    function error (err) {
      console.log(err)
    },

    function completed () {
      _self.$emit('upload-complete', 'hello')
      // accessing that reference using closure
    }

  )
}
```